# how to disable zoom/pinch in webView of ios 11

Tags: ios, webview, xcode9.1

I want to disable Zoom in zoom out in webview od ios 11. i use xcode 9 i used 
In my AppDelegate.m

1:-

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
  webView.scalesPageToFit = NO;
}
- (UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *) scrollView
{
  return nil;
}
```

2:-

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
  webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0;
  webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
}
- (UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *) scrollView
{
  return nil;
}
```

3:-

```
- (void)hijackWebViewScrollViewDelegate:(UIWebView *)webView {
  UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)[webView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
  scrollView.delegate = self;//xcode shows error in this is Assigning to 'id<UIScrollViewDelegate> _Nullable' from incompatible type 'AppDelegate *const __strong'**
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  return nil;
}
```

4:-I use this one in my AppDelegate.m and apply scrollViewDelegate in h no error but required is not achieved.

```
@implementation AppDelegate


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    webView.scrollView.delegate = self;
    webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0;
    webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    webView.scalesPageToFit = NO;
    webView.multipleTouchEnabled=NO;
}
- (UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *) scrollView
{
  return nil;
}
```

Comment: please see below my answer

Comment: if you can then insert this line into html file's _head_ tag anywhere: `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />`, that prevents the actual page being able to be zoomed in or out.

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me. I hope work for you!!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate{

    //MARK: UIScrollView Delegate Methods
    func scrollViewWillBeginZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?){
        scrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
        //For Avoid Zoom in Webview's content we are disable pinchGestureRecognizer
   }
}


//Objective-C 
//Use below code for Objective-C

-(void)scrollViewWillBeginZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view{
     [[scrollView pinchGestureRecognizer] setEnabled:false];
 }
```

Note : Don't forgot to add UIScrollviewDelegate

Comment: Thanks for help but not achieved my Appdelgate.m is                                                                             #import "AppDelegate.h" // i have added in this file UIScrollviewDelegate


  webView.scrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false // error with ? that requred symbol like : ternary